# How to find the point in the plane

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor

I have some known circles with r=1 (figure below, 4 circles are called C1 to C4). I want to find the nearest point to (0,0) not within the circles. is there any polynomial algorithm for this?

[image]

Comment: Surely, there is. What have you tried?

Comment: My first thought is that the closest point would either be the origin, the closest point to the origin on one of the circles, or the intersection of two circles.  You could check each one of these points explicitly and see which is closest and yet not inside another circle.

Comment: Can you give an example along with the desired answer? Does on the circle count?

Comment: I have added the solution for the example here.

Comment: Smallest circle inscribed in the union and centered at the origin?...

Comment: It is better to ask on [Math of Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have added a more simpler version on Math Exchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267737/how-to-find-the-best-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfectly ready-to-use answer, but only a draft for you to follow (Please let us know what you have tried next time).

1. if (0,0) is not covered by any circle, the answer will be (0,0)
2. if (0,0) is covered by 1 or more circles:

   (1) the nearest points on these circles (could be calculated by connecting and extending the center of the circle to (0,0)) which are not covered by any circle should be candidates;

   (2) all the cross point of these circles which are not covered by any circle should be candidates.

   (3) if (0,0) is the center of 1 or more circles, check if these circles are entirely covered by other circles. If not, add any one of the points on these circles which is not covered by any other circles to candidates.
3. find the minimum among the candidates.

Answer (score 1):

The closest point to origin will be one of the following:

- Intersection of two circles
- Intersection of circle and line connecting this circle center with the origin
- Origin itself if it does not lie inside any of the circles
- Infinite number of points on circle if this circle center is in origin

Check all those points, and find the closest amongst them with condition that this point does not lie inside some circle.

It will give you complexity O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

you may find for each point within the circles the lenght from point (0,0) and then find a minimum which neighbourhood is not within the circles.

Comment: there is no such points here. I want to find it. I could not brute force for all possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

The desired point is on the boundary of the union of all circles centered at the origin and maximally inscribed wihin some input circle Cn.

Algorithm:

For each input circle C_i with radius r_i centered at O_i (where O_i is d_i away from the origin, Oi_1^2 + Oi_2^2 = d_i^2), compute the inscribed radii u_i = r_i - d_i, and find their max. Some point u_max away from the origin is the solution

To find the actual point, suppose u_i = u_max for some i. Then the point you want is - O_i * u_i / d_i. If d_i = 0, then any point r_i away from the origin works.